# Strange result from multiplying string by number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel 2010, **"3-5" * 1** equals **41703**:

[image]

A number is returned for any string in this format, as long as the first number is between 1 and 12, and the second number is between 1 and 99.

Below is a "multiplication" table, which hints at a pattern, but it throws a real curve ball at times (note the highlighted cell):

[image]

**Questions:**

1. Can you confirm that other versions of Excel give the same results?
2. Is there a pattern here?

If the answers to both questions are, "Yes," then this may be something we can exploit, especially when working with array formulas.

Comment: It's so obvious now!!!  No wonder "2-30" is so bizarre.  Still wonder if it's exploitable.

Comment: "2-30" is still weird since all of the dates are of the present year, but "2-30" is in 1930.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In equivalent circumstances (eg locale) other versions of Excel will give the same results.
2. Yes, the pattern is the date.
   3-5 is being interpreted, for you, as March 5 (of this year) (Date serial number in 1900 system of 41703). The highlighted cell is because February does not have 30 days.

Comment: Thanks!  I had an idea for exploiting this in order to convert data like 4'11" to 59 inches.  But after the substituting required to convert `4'11"` to `4-11`, any advantage was lost.  (Plus, it's really unintuitive to convert `4-11` to inches like this:  `MONTH(A1)*12+DAY(A1)`)